# Jenkins & GitHub - Builds are not being triggered on push

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

This is how I have configured Jenkins:

#### GitHub project

[image]

#### Source Code Management

[image]

#### Build triggers

[image]

#### GitHub Plugin Config (Jenkins system configuration)

[image]

(the crossed out user would be **blablabla**, seen in the previous configs)

#### Token config on GitHub

[image]

When I push changes to that repo, nothing happens with the Jenkins job. I don't know what I'm doing wrong/what's lacking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that GitHub can't access your server.

The webhook is a POST that is sent from GitHub to the registered server. Since you're using a private IP address (172.17.x.x), GitHub can't contact your server. You'll need a publicly accessible web address in order for GitHub webhooks to work.

Comment: Is completely necessary to have the server accessible from the Internet for triggering builds on push to repo?

Comment: For GitHub, yes. But if you're on the same LAN as your Jenkins server, you could do client-side hooks. It's a little less straightforward than using GitHub hooks, but you can trigger Jenkins builds via a POST to a URL (essentially, the same thing GitHub would do). Check out [this page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), particularly post-commit and pre-push hooks.